# Why I'm getting a BLOB as default in MySQL row defined as VARCHAR(10)?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a new table in MySQL using MySQL Workbench 6.3 and set it the default value to be '0' but I'm getting a BLOB instead when I cast a SELECT

I created the columns with this

```
`ip1` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0',
`ip2` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0',
`ip3` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0',
`ip4` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0',
`ip5` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0',
`ip6` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0',
`ip7` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0',
`ip8` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0',
`ip9` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0',
`ip10` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '0',
```

and then I run this to avoid duplicates and keep the ip fields as they are.

```
REPLACE INTO  MainB.ReSendTo (accountID,deviceID,timestamp,statusCode) values('test','test123','1708100280','32');
```

All this fields on the REPLACE query are PK and I need that the rest of the fields, that are not PK, be 0 as default.

What I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**
Now I replaced REPLACE by INSERT IGNORE INTO and seems to work better but if I run this two querys the second one doesn't add a new row.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO  MainB.ReSendTo (accountID,deviceID,timestamp,statusCode) values('test','test123','1708100280','32');

INSERT IGNORE INTO  MainB.ReSendTo (accountID,deviceID,timestamp,statusCode) values('test','test123','1708100280','37');
```

Comment: It seems like you're asking two totally unrelated questions. You start out talking about casting a SELECT, but then you change to talking about using REPLACE.

Comment: As for the REPLACE issue, be aware that REPLACE is not UPDATE. REPLACE deletes the row, then it inserts a new row, using only the values specified in the tuple given. Values for all other columns are lost, and can only use NULL or the respective columns' defaults.

Comment: Also not related to your question, but it seems odd that you're using a version of MySQL Workbench from 2015. :-/

Comment: @BillKarwin I need to create a query to insert a new row but if the PK values combination exist do nothing. What should I do instead?

Comment: @BillKarwin I know is old, but is what the client use, the MySQL engine is also outdated but he refuse to update it. So I work with what I have.

Comment: Look into [`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: I found my mistake, I created the field column "timestamp" as unique. I altered the table and all the PK fields now are just PK. Anyway I don't understand why after an INSERT or REPLACE MySQL Workbench shows me ONE line, the first I created and not all and also the non PK field are BLOB. Now when I run a SELECT I got what I expect. Thanks for yous support.